# How can I restart the SSH server for Debian on Maru?

Tags: debian, ssh, maru-os

Is there a way to restart the SSH server on Maru without using the graphical interface in Debian?

Unfortunately, I only have an Ubuntu laptop at my disposal for configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to start the SSH server without a graphical interface, you need several things.

1. Install `ADB` and `Fastboot` on your ubuntu

`sudo apt install android-tools-adb android-tools-fastboot`

2. Enable the developer interface
3. Connect your device to your Ubuntu system using the USB cable and allow access for it.

Start the terminal on your laptop and enter `adb devices`.

If you find the device, enable root access with `adb root`, then enter `adb shell` to open a shell on the Maru device.

If that works, start the container with `lxc-start -n default`.

Now Maru should be running.

Enter your password and username, then enter `sudo su` to log in as root.

Enable the SSH server with '`systemctl enable ssh`, and then start it with `systemctl start ssh`.

Now your SSH server on the Maru device should be active and running.

Now your device just needs to be connected to your network. You can do this via Wi-Fi or using a USB network adapter.

Enter `hostname -I` to obtain the IP address.

You can also check the IP address in the `Settings > System > About phone > Status` section of your device.

Now you can log in with SSH.

Run this in your terminal, if you have not set a port `-p` or a key `-i`:

`ssh [USER]@[IP]`